# Python conditional triggering twice

Tags: python

I am practicing functions. I made a short game to practice functions. I use the input() to interact.

When I enter "End" is where the confusion begins.

```
def endgame():
    
    if input("Are you sure you want to exit?") == "yes" or input("Are you sure you want to exit?") == "y":
        
        return 1
    else:
        
        return 0
```

The input() is triggered on both sides of the OR condition if I select anything that is not "yes".
This is not what I expected. Here is the entire code.

```
#function calls

def picker(v):
    if v == "Game":
        somegame()
    elif v == "judo":
        judo()
    elif v == "End":
        #x = endgame()
        
        if endgame():
            print("Closing")
        else:
            print("Restarting")
            picker(input("Try to pick the secret again: "))
    else:
        picker(input("You must pick the secret: "))

    
def somegame():
    
    print("Some game")
    if input("Another game?") == "y":
        picker(input("Pick another game: "))
    else:
        print("Game ending")

def judo():
    
    print("Judo chop")
    
    if input("Another game?") == "y":
        picker(input("Pick another game: "))
    else:
        print("Game ending")


def endgame():    
    if input("Are you sure you want to exit?") == "yes" or input("Are you sure you want to exit?") == "y":        
        return 1
    else:        
        return 0

    
#Start the game here
picker(input("Pick the game: "))
```

I can see that if it doesn't match the first OR condition, it asks for input again. I believe it should ask once and compare the input to both variables. I assume this means I would have double calls if I used other functions within a IF/OR structure in the same way?

Storing the input() in a separate variable for comparison works, but I imagine other functions that I might make that return a value having this behavior.

```
def endgame():
    x = input("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    if x == "yes" or x == "y":        
        return 1
    else:        
        return 0
```

I know I am answering the question here, but the W3schools lesson doesnt describe this unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your last snippet of code is the right way: You have one `input()` and save that return value in `x`. You then test `x` to see what's in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions like this in Python are evaluated from left to right, until the required condition is met or the end of the statement has been reached. Calling the same method in an `or` statement will result in the method being called multiple times until the condition is met, or not.

Example,
`if 1 == 1 or 2 == 2 or 3 == 3` results in the rest of the condition past `1 == 1` to be totally ignored, since the whole condition has already been met. Somewhat similarly, `if 1 == 2 or 2 == 3 or 3 == 3` results in the first two conditions to be evaluated. If you were to put a condition after `3 == 3`, that would also be ignored assuming the previous condition (`3 == 3`) was `True`.

This sort of logic applies in conditions that incorporate `and` statements, though not exactly the same way depending on the circumstances of the `if` statement & its conditions.